# How to add JQuery code within a module in Joomla 3.1

Tags: joomla3.0

I am building a website using Joomla 3.1.4 and  trying to add jquery code within a module .The module will basically show jquery news ticker in the homepage.For that I have created a custom html module and tried to add jquery code within the "custom output" editor in admin panel.But it is not liking any jquery script overthere.Is there any way to add it? Where shall I get the files for this particular module in source to edit?

The jquery code which I like to add:

```
function tick(){

$('#ticker li:first').animate({'opacity':0}, 200, function () {     
    $(this).appendTo($('#ticker')).css('opacity', 1); });
}

setInterval(function(){ tick () }, 4000);
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, the editors are limited in code and some tags. The way you have to add it is to code it in your module. You can either add the script or a snippet:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addScriptDeclaration("
    // Your jQuery or js script hoes here. ex:
    (function($){
        $(document).ready(function(){
            // Your jQuery methods inside
        });
    })(jQuery);
");
```

or you can call a script from a directory:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument(); 
$url = "/your_dir/your_script.js";
$doc->addScript($url, $type="text/javascript");
```

Note the difference between the two: one adds a script, the second a script file. Hope it helps.